# How can I get parameters out of a string and store them in variables?

Tags: c#, string, parameters

I have a single string downloaded that will have this format:

```
  "MatchId": "83570b03-2963-4b44-834c-bf77c74f2d0a",
  "MatchType": 3,
  "GameMode": 3,
  "SeasonId": null,
  "PlaylistId": "282fc197-7bf1-4865-81ec-a312d07567b6",
  "Teams": {
    "1": {
      "TeamSize": 2
    },
    "2": {
      "TeamSize": 2
    }
  },
  "MapId": "skirmish\\design\\MP_Veteran\\MP_Veteran",
  "MatchStartDate": {
    "ISO8601Date": "2017-02-24T21:20:42.024Z"
  },
  "PlayerMatchDuration": "PT35M39.4550853S",
  "PlayerIndex": 3,
  "TeamId": 1,
  "TeamPlayerIndex": 1,
  "LeaderId": 3,
  "PlayerCompletedMatch": true,
  "PlayerMatchOutcome": 2,
  "XPProgress": {
    "PreviousTotalXP": 23300,
    "GameplayXP": 600,
    "ChallengesXP": 0,
    "UpdatedTotalXP": 23900,
    "CompletedSpartanRanks": []
```

What I want to know is if I have a separate class with variables such as `MatchId`, `MatchType`, `GameMode` etc. How can I input this string and automatically store all of the values into the correct variable?

Comment: well, it looks like a json file so NewtonSoft.JSON seems like a good option to start your coding

Comment: Thanks - this did the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like JSON, does this have a surrounding `{` and `}`? If so you need to parse it as JSON which should be pretty easy if you use something like what Icepickle suggested (NewtonSoft.JSON)

Comment: It does have a surrounding { } yes.
I have not used JSON before but I will lookup NewtonSoft

Comment: Also I then have them added to a TreeView, how can I iterate through and add all the child nodes. eg GameEvent>XPProgress>PreviousTotalXP  
They don't always all have the same children, for example they wont always have a "GameMode" so how can I only add nodes for the children it has

Comment: @user2758663 That's a new question, but see it like a `Dictionary<string, object>` where the value might be a new dictionary string object ;)